# Data shifting from one account to other in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are using Autodesk Forge for one of our client's AEC application. When we were in the POC phase we used our own Forge account and started to add files and get translated viewable.
Now the next phase has started and I want my data to be moved inside the client's own account. Is it possible to just move the stored files and viewable into the other account as we don't want to spend credits on re-translation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's exactly possible - this is a request that has been raised to Engineering and I will come back to update this answer when they make this happen.

Far as I know the easiest approach would be to transfer the Forge app that has access to the derivatives to your client. To do so simply send the Forge app id along with the recipient's account ID to forge.help@autodesk.com from the email address of the account owner and we will proceed with the transfer.